# Evaluating intermediate function values only once

Tags: scala

I need a function that will translate and scale a complex number, i.e if `z` is complex, the fuction should return `( z - translate ) * scale`
The function is to be parametrized by the dimensions of the screen and the scaling factor, here is what I have:

```
def affTransform(width: Int, height: Int, scaleFactor: Double)(z: Complex): Complex = {
    val scale: Double = 4.0 / width
    val translate = Complex(width / 2, height / 2)
    (z - translate) * scale
}
```

With this in place, the following works as expected:

```
val transform: Complex => Complex = affTransform(W, H, 4)    
...
val zz: Complex = transform(z)
```

The problem is that the calculation:

```
    val scale: Double = 4.0 / width
    val translate = Complex(width / 2, height / 2)
```

is performed every time `transform` is applied which is conceptually redundant. This is also the case when `affTransform` is not curried and `transform` is defined as partially applied.

Is there a way to define `affTransform` and\or `transform` so that `scale` and `translate` are calculated only once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply take away the last of the argument lists and return a function instead:

```
case class Complex(re: Double, im: Double) {
  def - (that: Complex) = Complex(this.re - that.re, this.im - that.im)
  def * (scalar: Double) = Complex(re * scalar, im * scalar)
}

def aff(width: Int, height: Int, scaleFactor: Double): Complex => Complex = {
  println("Heavy calculation here...")
  val scale: Double = 4.0 / width
  val translate = Complex(width / 2, height / 2)
  z: Complex => (z - translate) * scale
}

val transform: Complex => Complex = aff(640, 480, 4)
transform(Complex(12, 34))
```

Comment: Ah, so the calculated values in `aff` become constructor values for the function returned by `aff`

Comment: Yes, they are caught by the `z` closure and therefore "fixed". This is similar to currying your original method, only that the curried function would run the calculation of `scale` and `translate` over and over again.

Comment: By the way, the pre-calculation doesn't need to be "heavy", in this case it is invoked many times ( `width * height` times) and the original code generates a lot of unnecessary garbage (e.g. `640 * 480 = 307200` instances of Complex)